# MySql cannot be used error installing testlink using PHP 7.x from Xampp

Tags: php, mysql, windows, xampp, testlink

I am in the process of installing testlink, it always gives out an error saying MySQL cannot be used. I use PHP 7.x from Xampp

I installed all requirements for testlink from Xampp. Tried out removing some ; from php.ini production and development files. Issue still persists.

Comment: can you add the exact error code and the lines you removed from php.ini

Comment: Could your database issue be related to this noted in the Requirements Mysql or mariaDB must have this parameter set `log_bin_trust_function_creators`